# Trello API call types not working after a webHooks request

Tags: trello

I am trying to get a useful list of WebHooks that are setup.
I am successfully making the call to get the webHooks:

//api.trello.com/1/tokens/[token]/webhooks?key[key]&token=[token]

to which I get the correct return:

[{
      "id":"57cdaeb017c9e258024a7b14",
      "description":"PV-Trello-Bot webhook #1",
      "idModel":"57650a686df0aee33d098fb3",
      "callbackURL":"http://myIP:8080/PV-Trello-Bot/pvTrelloBot/notification",
      "active":true
   }]

I then want to find out what type of object this webHook relates to so I am calling the types call with the modelID from the previous response:

//api.trello.com/1/types/57650a686df0aee33d098fb3?key=[key]&token=[token]

to which I am getting a 404 error. "model not found".

What am I doing wrong? Or what have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

My read of the documentation is that types can only be used for teams or users: https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/type